# Get a list of values from SQL statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I don't quite understand how to take an input that is referring to TABLE and utilize it to return a proper value.

Basically, what I would like to do is have a LEVEL-OBJECT pair as an input.

From that pair, I want to get a SERIAL out from it.

However, since OBJECT is not unique, I also want the output to include any other SERIAL from OBJECT-LEVEL pairs where OBJECT is the same as the original input.

Basically, I need to get a list out, but I am not sure how to do so.

Moreover, not shown in this example, but I need to check if the list is NULL and traverse up the tree from the original LEVEL until I have a serial number to return.

All I have been able to get out is one return value, but if my input is:

```
LEVEL  : D
OBJECT : 2
```

I should be getting:

```
X2, X3
```

TABLE:

```
LEVEL(UNIQUE) | OBJECT | PARENT | ROOT | SERIAL

     A        | NULL   |  NULL  |  A   |  NULL

     B        | NULL   |   A    |  A   |  NULL

     C        |   1    |   B    |  A   |  X1

     D        |   2    |   C    |  A   |  X2

     E        |   2    |   D    |  A   |  X3
```

This is the base that I am using, and I've tried about 25 different ways of getting a list of results, but to no avail:

```
 SELECT Serial FROM Object AS Output
 WHERE (LEVEL = 'E' AND OBJECT = 2);
```

Comment: Show proper examples. And for going up in the tree, you need a [recursiv common table expression](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/747/common-table-expressions/2538/recursively-going-up-in-a-tree).

Comment: I don't think I need to recursively go up the tree -- I just need to check if the list that I want to output is null, and if it is, get the serial number for the parent. while(List isNULL){LEVEL = currentlevel.parent; add SERIAL to list, if it has one, otherwise, continue to the current levels parent}

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: @Strawberry I am using sqlite. Apologies for two different tags.

Comment: @CL. Recursion is also extremely costly in the example that you sent me to for what I am attempting to do.

Comment: Recursion is the only mechanism that can implement that while loop.

Comment: @CL. Understood. My knowledge of sql is minimal, at best, and recursion just doesn't sound right, but I am starting to understand a bit more of what you are saying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values of all rows with the same `Object`, filter only for that (`WHERE Object = ?`).
To search for a non-NULL serial, you need to go up the tree with a [recursive common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte) until you have found a valid serial:

```
WITH RECURSIVE Output AS (
  SELECT Level, Parent, Serial
  FROM Object
  WHERE Object = 2

  UNION ALL

  SELECT Object.Level, Object.Parent, Object.Serial
  FROM Object
  JOIN Output ON Object.Level = Output.Parent
  WHERE Output.Serial IS NULL
)
SELECT Serial         -- use DISTINCT to avoid duplicates
FROM Output
WHERE Serial IS NOT NULL;
```